# How should I factorize a differential equation from the first order but with higher degrees?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My question is the following:

How should I factorize a differential equation from the first order but with higher degrees?

Imagine I have:

$$x^2(y')^2+xyy'-6y^2 = 0$$

Is it okay if I replace $y'$ with $p$ and just solve the equation for $p$ with $x$ and $y$ being constants?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is a valid method. Doing this via factorization, you can divide your differential equation by $x^2$ to obtain:
$$(y')^2+\frac{y}{x}y'-\frac{6y^2}{x^2}=0$$
If you want to make the factorization easier to visualize, you can let $u=\frac{y}{x}$ for example. Doing this should give you:
$$\left(y'+3\cdot \frac{y}{x}\right)\left(y'-2\cdot \frac{y}{x}\right)=0$$
This will give you two separate first order ODE's to solve:
$$\begin{align} y'&=-\frac{3y}{x} \\ y'&=\frac{2y}{x} \end{align} \tag{1}$$
They are both separable.

---

Alternatively, you can use the quadratic formula on your original ODE to solve for $y'$:
$$y'=\frac{-xy\pm \sqrt{(xy)^2+24x^2y^2}}{2x^2}=\frac{-y\pm \sqrt{25y^2}}{2x}=\frac{-y\pm 5y}{2x}$$
Giving you the same two first-order ODE's obtained on $(1)$.